# Alamofire pinning for shared Manager

Tags: ios, alamofire

In **Alamofire 3.0** How can I set my own `ServerTrustPolicyManager` for shared Manager? My goal is set SSL pinning (e.g. bundled public SSL key) for whole app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You MUST create a custom `Manager` to do this.